# MySQL: Order by a function of two columns

Tags: php, python, mysql, sql

I have two integer fields A and B in table T .

I want to do something like "`SELECT * FROM T ORDER BY f(A,B) DESC`"

where `f(A,B)` is a linear combination of A and B ... i.e `f(A,B) = mA + nB`, where m and n are numbers.

What is the right syntax?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have two options (at least):

```
SELECT (n * A + m * B) AS C, *
  FROM T
 ORDER BY C DESC; -- or ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

Or:

```
SELECT *
  FROM T
 ORDER BY (n * A + m * B) DESC;
```

One or the other - possibly both - should work for you in MySQL.  The first should work even if the second does not.

Answer (score 5):

Try to keep it simple, use the following:

```
SELECT * FROM T ORDER BY (m * A + n * B) DESC
```

where m and n are on your responsibility.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - thanx, forgot about asterics 8-)